# Search in GVIM word with "/" and "["

Tags: vim

I want to search in gvim words that include the below symbols

```
"/" & "["
```

each time I need to add backslash.
Is there any GVIM configuration to prevent doing it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Perform a non-regex search/replace in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254820/perform-a-non-regex-search-replace-in-vim)

Comment: You may like the solutions provided here: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Searching_for_expressions_which_include_slashes